# Why Limit is not working in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

My question is why the ORDER BY and LIMIT was not working in the concerned query? Sometimes, it returns 1 row which is correct and sometimes it returns all rows (by join). Is there any known issues of MySQL regarding this?

```
select t1.*, t2.c_value 
from table1 t1
inner join table2  t2 on t1.id = t2.f_id
where table1.user_id = 139 
order by table1.id desc 
limit 0,1
```

Comment: Is there a 1 to 1 relationship?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: instead of saying `limit 0,1` what if you say `limit 1`?

Comment: Do you mean if you repeat that exact query you sometimes get 1 result & other times all results? Or do you mean with different conditions - for example different user_id.